# Дебаг кода airflow в pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, анализ-данных, big-data, airflow

Подскажите, существует ли действительно рабочий способ дебагинга кода airflow в pycharm? Не хочется часами отлавливать ошибки через ui интерфейс airflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931845/debugging-airflow-tasks-with-ide-tools